# Integration of the partial derivative of a homogeneous function of degree zero

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Suppose $f\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n \backslash \{0\})$ satisfies $f(\lambda x)= f(x)$ for $\lambda >0$, and it has zero average on $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$.

My question is: how can we show that its n-th partial derivative $\frac{\partial^n f}{\partial x_{i}^n}$ also has zero average on the unit sphere?

This is just a sentence in a proof regarding the kernel of some certain type of singular integrals, but it’s not obvious.

Comment: Note: The functions you describe in the question are _not_ radial! (With one exception: A radial function with the two properties you assume must be identically zero.)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Sorry, I have edited.

Comment: ??? The change you made has is irrelevant to my comment. A function is _radial_ if $f(x)$ depends only on $|x|$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Oh, yes, I meant homogeneous of degree 0.